# Laravel Mix task flow

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to include browserSync in my `webpack.mix.js` for my laravel project.

The problem is that browserSync reloads browser before other tasks executes.

How should I configure my `webpack.mix.js` for browserSync reload page only after other tasks?

**Here is my webpack.mix.js:**

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .browserSync({
        proxy: 'workflow.dev'
    });
```

Comment: You could try and break it up like the documentation so you are not chaining it onto other commands. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/browsersync.md

Comment: I guess the most important question here is why do you need that? If you're using laravel-mix, I guess you're already expecting that mix deals with this, not you. If you'd like to be more incisive on the mix flow, you either have three options: 1) use the options provided and forget about this; 2) contribute to the package yourself; 3) implement your own webpack implementation to that (just remembering that you can have an specific webpack.config.js for a project). I really don't think this is a relevant question... =S